# How to share a variable between epics that are in different files?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, next.js, redux-observable

I'm using [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/) in my [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) web application. There is a variable which has to be set in `epic1` and accessed later in `epic2`:

```
let sharedVariable;

const epic1 = (action$, state$) => {
    return action$.pipe(
        // check if the dispatched action is of type action1
        filter(action1.match),
        tap((action) => {
            // create a new instance of A and assign
            // it to sharedVariable
            if (!sharedVariable) {
                sharedVariable = new A();
            }
        }),
        mergeMap((action) => {
            ...
        }),
    )
}

const epic2 = (action$, state$) => {
    return action$.pipe(
        // check if the dispatched action is of type action2
        filter(action2.match),
        map((action) => {
            if (sharedVariable) {
                return action3();
            } else {
                return action4();
            }
        }),
    )
}
```

I want to put the epics on different files: `epics1.js` & `epics2.js`

How should I enable the epics to set and access the `sharedVariable` when they are located on different files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like good case for DI: [docs](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html)

```js
const sharedVariable = {} // can not be primitive type
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware({
  dependencies: { sharedVariable }
});

const epic2 = (action$, state$, { sharedVariable }) => {
 // Rest of code
}
```